# How to enter formulas in Excel in other locales (with different decimal separators)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, locale

I'm getting a strange error in Excel where I cannot enter formulas:

```
=ROUND(1.5,0)
```

gives an error:

> The formula you typed contains an error

[image]

I presume it has something to do with the (*red herring*) fact that I am in a locale that uses:

- `.` for decimal point
- `,` for digit grouping
- `,,` for list separation

[image]

How do I enter these formulas in Excel?

---

**Update**: semi-colon doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Can you try `=ROUND(1.5;0)`?

Comment: Try Alt+0132, because that looks like a single character, not two commas.

Comment: @Mepher C. Palavuzlar: That doesn't work: "The formula you typed contains an error"

Comment: @Excelll: You can't use Alt+keypad codes in Excel; it interprets keypad strokes as navigation, and trues to leave the cell

Comment: @Ian Boyd: Keypad codes work just fine in Excel.  Maybe you don't have NumLock on?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can enter the formula in a less funky locale? When I enter it with the list separator beeing "," and save, the formula is working even when I open the file with the list separator set to ,,. In that case the separator gets displayed as a blank, and when I look closer it's really a blank (Unicode 0x0020)

However, when I want to enter that in the formula as separator, I get the same error you see.

Comment: Semicolon doesn't work. Updated question with screenshot proof.

Comment: oops. my bad. I had the very same problem the other day, but my solution doesn't fit your problem ;-( funky. let me try in Excel.

Comment: The locale might be a red herring; it's the only reason i can imagine why excel is now choking on some pretty standard stuff.

Comment: edited the answer. I do think it's the locale, and I think that maybe the formula handling is different from cell handling.

Comment: just checked with a Unicode … as list separator - that works. Any chance you could use a Unicode character as list separator? Guess: while Windows tolerates a two-char list separator, Excel formulas do not.

Comment: i guess update your answer to say, "It's a bug in Excel and cannot be done" and i'll accept it.

Comment: I'll try to get a RealAnswer(tm) from MSFT. Will update when I hear something back. Don't hold your breath, though.

Comment: There's an *accepted answer* in it for ya if ya do! :P

Comment: now that should get me going ;-)