# Where is the bug reporting/feedback for Office/Excel?

Tags: microsoft-office, connection, microsoft-office-2010

I've found a [bug in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/333767/how-to-enter-formulas-in-excel-in-other-locales-with-different-decimal-separator/333802#333802), and I'm trying to find the place to report it to Microsoft.

Normally I would check [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/). But not only is there no active place to submit [feedback on Office](http://connect.microsoft.com/directory/?keywords=office), there [never was](http://connect.microsoft.com/directory/) any place to submit feedback on Excel.

I know there must be a place to report issues with Office. Where is it?

Comment: Someone's experience trying to file a bug report with microsoft: http://weblog.timaltman.com/archive/2006/03/22/reporting-bugs-microsoft

Comment: @MaQleod As that blog post contains the mailing address, you should really post this as an answer.

Comment: Back in the mid-to-late 1990s at a Windows 95 presentation at a local computer club someone asked about this, and the presenter said to simply call technical support and they'd take the report for free.

Comment: _You only found one bug?  You must be a new Excel user._  ;-D

Comment: Pretty hard to find bugs. i got it in a use-case that would never happen to anyone intentionally finding ways to break applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't look like there is a page to "submit bugs." You should read [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/Connect/feedback/details/652240/office-2010-is-not-available-for-bug-reports).

> JamesJohnston,
>
> Thank you for your submission, however the Connect Website Improvement connection is not the place to file suggestions for other Microsoft products or services. While we have aspirations for creating a central feedback repository for all products in one place, that goal has not yet been achieved.
>
> At this time, all feedback on released products and services should be directed to the Microsoft Support page (http://support.microsoft.com/select/?target=hub).
>
> Based on the above information, we are resolving your submission as External since this is not an issue we can address.
>
> John
> Microsoft Connect Team

***Dated: 3/21/2011***